# Python - using TSV files to find averages

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, key-value

I am working on a lab project for school and am completely lost on how to do it. The following code is as far i have gotten after watching a few hours of python videos and googling for info on how to do this. The instructions are as follows:

> Write a program that reads the student information from a tab seperated values (tsv) file. The program then creates a text file that records the course grades of the students. Each row of the tsv file contains the Last Name, First Name, Midterm1 score, Midterm2 score, and the Final score of a student. A sample of the student information is provided in StudentInfo.tsv. Assume the number of students is at least 1 and at most 20. Assume also the last names and first names do not contain whitespaces.
>
> The program performs the following tasks:
>
> - Read the file name of the tsv file from the user
> - Open the tsv file and read the student information.
> - Compute the average exam score of each student.
> - Assign a letter grade to each student based on the average exam score in the following scale:
>
>   A: 90 =< x
>
>   B: 80 =< x < 90
>
>   C: 70 =< x < 80
>
>   D: 60 =< x < 70
>
>   F: x < 60
> - Compute the average of each exam.
> - Output the last names, first names, exam scores, and letter grades of the students into a text file named report.txt. Output one student per row and seperate the values with a tab character.
> - Output the average of each exam, with two digits after the decimal point, at the end of report.txt.

It comes with a downloadable files named StudentInfo.tsv. The contents of which are just:

> Barrett    Edan    70    45    59 
> Bradshaw    Reagan    96    97    88 
> Charlton    Caiuss    73    94    80 
> Mayo    Tyrese    88    61    36 
> Stern    Brenda    90    86    45

I am going about the assignment by making a dictionary and adding the items from the tsv file to the dictionary in key/value pairs. I was wondering if A) what i had so far seemed okay, and B) how would i go about calling forth individual key/values to find the average? For example, I have all the midterm1 scores (the first score in each user's row) assigned to the key "midterm1" in the dictionary and was wondering how i could call just those keys for each user to find the average? I have only worked with dictionaries where you would utilize every key and not just specific ones. I know my code will need some formatting arguments put in place to get the output right, but for now, all i have is:

```
import csv
user_file = input()
students = {}

with open("{user_file}") as file: # Unsure if this is how you use a variable to open a file
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
    students.append({"last_name": row[0], "first_name": row[1], "midterm1": row[2], "midterm2": row[3], "final": row[4]})

for student in sorted(students, key = lambda student: student["last_name"]):
    student_avg = ((int(students["midterm1"]) + int(students["midterms2"] + int(students{"final"])) / 3)
    if student_avg >= 90:
        student_grade == "A"
    elif 80 <= student_avg < 90:
        student_grade == "B"
    elif 70 <= student_avg < 80:
        student_grade == "C"
    elif 60 <= student_avg < 70:
        student_grade == "D"
    elif student_avg < 60:
        student_grade == "F"
    students.update({"letter_grade": student_grade}) # hoping this adds a new key/value to the list

midterm1_avg = 0
midterm2_avg = 0
final_avg = 0

# Time to calculate the averages
for "midterm1", value in students(): # this is where I am stuck. I don't even know if this will work or not.
```

I appreciate anyone taking the time to read this in advance. I am about 3-4 weeks into my python journey and this site has been invaluable. If you see anything I am doing that could be written in a shorter format, i am all ears. For this class we don't use too many of the import features of python outside of the math module and csv. But i am always interested in seeing better real world examples of how it should be coded.

Answer (score 0):

You define students as a dict and then try to use method "append", no can do.
Dict has no such method. Define it as a list

```
students = []
```

You forgot the "f" for f-string

```
with open(f"{user_file}") as file:
```

You have to indent the line with "append" (so that it's executed IN the for loop)

When calculating student_avg you have to reference student (your current element in loop), not student**S** (the whole list of dicts)

When you iterate over a list of students your student is a dict
So you update the entry like this:

```
student["letter_grade"] = student_grade
```

Regarding the averages you can accumulate them in the same loop where you assign letter grades (assign 0 to them before the loop):

```
midterm1_average += student.get("midterm1", 0)
midterm2_average += student.get("midterm2", 0)
final_average += student.get("final", 0)
```

And then after the loop just divide by the number of students:

```
number_of_students = len(students)
midterm1_average /= number_of_students
midterm2_average /= number_of_students
final_average /= number_of_students
```

In general you are pretty close and the code is decent. Try to visualize your data structures, maybe even print them (what is students, what is a particular student when you loop over them and so on). Also run your code. It would fail multiple times and it's faster to write and debug simultaneously, than write everything and debug later.

Comment: Thank you for this information! You have helped me immensely!